# CSS Pixel and Percentages Used Together

Tags: css

Quite new to web design so I am reading a few books to get up to speed.

In Javascript Novice to Ninja I have come across the following  css code in an example.

```
header{
  font: bold 36px/120% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

}

I have never seen PX and % used this way. 
Could someone please explain if this is correct code and if it is how it is working? Is this setting the font first to 36px then to 120%? 
Thank you all in advance for your time.

Comment: syntax is in form of font-size/line-height

Answer (score 2):

`36px/120%` is `font-size/line-height`

`font` shorthand is used in the example.

`font: style variant weight size/line-height family;`

`font-size` is always specified with a `unit` (`px`, `em`, `rem` etc), `line-height` is specified with a `/` just after the `font-size`; [`unit less` line-height is preferred](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Prefer_unitless_numbers_for_line-height_values).